# Resizing a partition with gparted resulted in an error, how do I recover the old Linux ext3 partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery, ext3, gparted

Well, gparted crapped on me, and I was dumb enough to not keep the log file.

Basically, I was trying to increase the size of my main (home) linux partition, and in the middle of the gparted operation (from a live CD), gparted encountered an error. After rebooting the system, the system was no longer bootable. Rebooting again with the live CD showed that not even Linux understands the old partition it just said "unknown" for 'type.'

Anyone know how to at least get the home directory back from that partition? I'm very open to suggestions, including long ones like "recreate the partition table one character at a time" so long as there are descent instructions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under similar circumstances [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) saved my bacon a few times. They have instructions on the site itself

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. Data loss sucks